# 'Thank you for this opportunity' in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german, meaning-in-context

How can I say "Thanks a lot for this opportunity!" in German?

My guess is "Vielen Dank für diese Gelegenheit!". Should I use *Gelegenheit* or *Möglichkeit?*

I received a scholarship to attend a language course in Germany, and I want to thank the teachers for giving me this opportunity.

Comment: Most likely neither but a subordinate clause like *dass ich mein Konzept präsentieren durfte* / *mich vorstellen durfte* or similar.

Comment: With the update I would translate *Vielen Dank für das Stipendium!*, but I'm not convinced, that this should address the teachers (as opposed to the sponsors).

Comment: Translation requests are off topic. The grammar is correct, but word for word translations can become unidiomatic, IMHO a very American thing to say, lost in translation. Maybe detail the question with why you doubt either option, and note that "thank you" can mean various things and thus translate differently. How about you wait for the course to start? Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3):

In a formal context you can say:

> Ich bedanke mich sehr bei Ihnen für diese Gelegenheit.

If you want to be more specific I'd use the following words:

> Ich bedanke mich bei Ihnen, dass Sie mir die Gelegenheit gegeben
>   haben, [etw. zu tun]

Comment: The *um* ist wrong. *Ich bedanke mich bei Ihnen, dass Sie mir die Gelegenheit gegeben haben, meinen Hut aufzusetzen.*

Comment: Beispiel 2) finde ich "natürlicher"

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on context. If it was the opportunity to talk to someone, you'd say *Danke für Ihre Aufmerksamkeit*; Or you could say *Danke, daß Sie es mir ermöglicht haben, X zu tun*. Usually the actual opportunity is obvious from the situation, so just saying *Vielen Dank* or *Vielen Dank dafür* might be sufficient.

Comment: Würde man im Deutschen "Vielen Dank für diese Gelegenheit!" nicht sagen, dann würde ich Dir zustimmen, dass man Deine Vorschläge stattdessen umsetzen könnte; man sagt es aber durchaus.

Comment: In der Tat. Der Unterschied ist wohl das "diese", wo auf eine konkrete Gelegenheit hingewisen wird. Das klingt etwas natürlicher als ein bloßes "die Gelegenheit".

Comment: Man kann vieles sagen, Richtiges und Falsches, stilistisch Gelungenes und Danebengegangenes, und all das ordnet man nach seinen sprachlichen Erfahrungen ein und hat dazu eine Einschätzung. "Vielen Dank für diese Gelegenheit" finde auch ich ziemlich steif, "für diese super Gelegenheit" wäre schon etwas flotter, aber da würde ich darauf warten, dass der Satz irgendwie weitergeht, vielleicht "Deutsch im Land selbst zu lernen". Oder, ähnlich wie Oliver: "Danke, dass Sie das für mich möglich gemacht haben / dass Sie mir diese tolle Chance eröffnet haben..."